# Interacting with Ethereum Smart Contract that has been deployed via address

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I am total beginner in Ethereum so how to interact with smart contract via address ? 
here is the address : 0x259a065256212183490b3ee3f4702c900c37d712

Or did I miss something ?

Comment: You missed there being a [dedicated Ethereum site](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/). Question doesn't appear to be on-topic for SO.

Comment: That depends on how you want to interact with it. If you have the contracts ABI, you can load the address and ABI into MEW and interact with it that way. You can verify the code on ether scan and play with it there and many many other ways. Can you be more specific about what you are trying to do?